# is this temporary login method terrible?

Tags: mysql, security, validation

I was just thinking of possible ways to go about temporary login systems. I was thinking having a bunch of your standard images with a jumbled up word and users type in the word. I would have a MySQL table where all the photos have a unique id, link and answer-key. that way the webpage just has to choose a random number the GET photo where id = random number. then compare what the user types in to the answer key of the photo.

I'm not currently trying to create this system, it seems very simple and I was just trying to  think if it is a secure system that would work.

so my question really is, would there security risks with this, is it robust enough to keep out bots, would my site be destroyed 10 seconds after implementing it.

Comment: This site is for concrete programming problems. We are not here to vet your designs, or do the design for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing sounds exactly like a CAPTCHA system. These are used widely to prevent bots from issuing automated requests against an interface. The problem is that it's hard to make images that a bot can't just interpret anyway.

[Outsmarted: Captcha security not much of a gotcha](http://www.cnet.com/news/outsmarted-captcha-security-not-much-of-a-gotcha/) is an article about some Stanford researchers who developed an image-recognition tool (which is not publicly available) to test captcha implementations:

> Decaptcha was able to decode 66 percent of the Captchas used by Visa's Authorize.net payment site, 70 percent of Blizzard Entertainment's Captchas -- the company's games include World of Warcraft and Diablo -- and 25 percent of Wikipedia's. About one-fifth of Digg.com's Captchas and almost that many of CNN.com's were decodable.

The researchers recommended [Google's reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) as a much more effective system. You can add a reCAPTCHA widget to your own website. This would be safer and easier than trying to develop your own and find it to be too weak.

Comment: Captchas are getting so ridiculous now there are times when I could use a browser-plugin to automatically decode them for me.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it's not secure. If someone really wants to hack your system he can build his own database of image-word.

The key is to invest in security less than it will cost you if your system will be compromise, so I won't invest in a security system too much (it sounds like you don't really have a sensitive information to hide).

BUT, you have an easy & free solution. You can use [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/), not only it's much more secured, you'll help digitize some useful information.